# How to exclude some audio assets on different platforms?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8.1, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am releasing an app for iOS, Windows Phone 8.1 and Android.
As a result, I have the same audio tracks in mp3, OGG, and WAV.

Since I don't need all three in each platform (only mp3 in iOS, OGG in Android, WAV in windows phone etc), where should I keep the files so that during the build process the correct files are included when building for a particular platform?

For example, on iOS I don't need the OGG and WAV files (WAV files are huge!), so where should I keep the files ? Or how do I exclude them for a particular platform ?

Answer (score 0):

In Android:
 In project folder-> inside res folder-> create raw folder and copy your OGG files. That's it... Now you can call this file using getResourse() method.

In iOs:
 Put in project folder-> after that you need to entry in build phase-> copy bundle resource path.

In Windows Phone 8.1:
 Add the audio to your project. (You might use a subfolder named 'Assets'). Specify the path properly. Make the build action property content and access the file using full file path.

Comment: I put the audio file in my project folder, and automatically an entry was added in the build phase (copy bundle resource). But when I run the game it breaks at "        audioSourcePlayer = [(AVAudioPlayer*)[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
"  (I have Xcode set to break at All Exceptions, and malloc_error_break). So  there is some mistake. Can you explain in more detail ?

Comment: The file appears to be at that location when I check in finder.

Comment: The problem is not in audio file adding. Update your playing code maybe i can help you.